# Portable way to check if an environment variable is set

Tags: bash, dash-shell

In Bash you can check if an environment variable is set with `test -v FOO`. It doesn't work in Dash on Debian 11 though because its `test` doesn't support `-v`:

```
# test -v FOO
dash: 2: test: -v: unexpected operator
```

Is there a portable way that works in Bash and Dash (and ideally more shells, but those are the main ones I am concerned with)?

Comment: Don't know if `dash` supports parameter testing, but try just `Testr="xyz";unset Testr; echo ${Testr:?}` . I get `-ksh93: Testr: parameter not set`. Good luck.

Comment: Had a typo, check above code again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `+` in the expansion of the variable, and test it:

```bash
test "${FOO+x}"
```

The expansion results in an empty string if `FOO` is unset, or `x` otherwise.